# How can I make apply_async to accept messagegroupid parameter for sqs fifo queue

Tags: celery, boto3, amazon-sqs, message-queue, task-queue

the problem I am having is that celery's apply_async is not delivering a required keyword argument, MessageGroupId, to sendmessage method of boto3 to publish message to sqs fifo queue.

I have been trying to use celery's apply_async task to publish messages on sqs fifo queue, and first I got the following error:

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MissingParameter) when calling the SendMessage operation: The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.

So I found out that for fifo message queues, we need to pass MessageGroupId as a keywork argument to apply_async as described in celery's documentation [here:](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html#:%7E:text=Django%20Admin%20monitor.-,With%20FIFO,-queues%20it%20might).

I did pass the messagegroupid parameter as a keyword argument, but I faced the same error. for some reason, the MessageGroupId parameter is not being accepted by SendMessage operation.

Can someone help me out in solving this issue

Comment: Can I see your code? I am relatively new to celery but your code can help me understand your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was looking for the same question and this was the first post on google: celery docs answers you question:

> With FIFO queues it might be necessary to set additional message
> properties such as MessageGroupId and MessageDeduplicationId when
> publishing a message.
>
> Message properties can be passed as keyword arguments to
> `apply_async()`:
>
> ```
> message_properties = {
>     'MessageGroupId': '<YourMessageGroupId>',
>     'MessageDeduplicationId': '<YourMessageDeduplicationId>'
> }
> task.apply_async(**message_properties)
> ```

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html